# SQL Server, find an arbitrary sequence of values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Let's assume we have a table Maintenance

```
Customer LastLogin ActionType
1        12/1/2007 2
1        12/2/2007 2
etc.
```

We want a list of all customers who at any point during a given year had one or more uninterrupted sequences, 14 days long, of login with action type 2.

I can of course easily do this with code, and even have it be fairly quick over small sets.  Is there a non-cursor way to do it in SQL?

Comment: Edited for clarity guys.  We're looking for long(er) running sequences, not just two in a row.

Comment: You do this AFTER I post my code? You know I had to write the code sitting on my chair but facing UPHILL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will select all customers with at least two consecutive actions of the same type.

```
WITH    rows AS 
        (
        SELECT  customer, action,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY lastlogin) AS rn
        FROM    mytable
        )
SELECT  DISTINCT customer
FROM    rows rp
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    rows rl
        WHERE   rl.customer = rp.customer
                AND rl.rn = rp.rn + 1
                AND rl.action = rp.action
        )
```

Here's the more efficient query for just action `2`:

```
WITH    rows AS 
        (
        SELECT  customer, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY lastlogin) AS rn
        FROM    mytable
        WHERE   action = 2
        )
SELECT  DISTINCT customer
FROM    rows rp
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    rows rl
        WHERE   rl.customer = rp.customer
                AND rl.rn = rp.rn + 1
        )
```

**Update 2:**

To select uninterrupted ranges:

```
WITH    rows AS 
        (
        SELECT  customer, action, lastlogin
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer ORDER BY lastlogin) AS rn
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer, action ORDER BY lastlogin) AS series
        FROM    mytable
        )
SELECT  DISTINCT customer
FROM    (
        SELECT  customer
        FROM    rows rp
        WHERE   action
        GROUP BY
                customer, actioncode, series - rn
        HAVING
                DETEDIFF(day, MIN(lastlogin), MAX(lastlogin)) >= 14
        ) q
```

This query calculates two series: one returns contiguous `ORDER BY lastlogin`, the second one partitions by `action` additionally:

```
action  logindate rn  series diff = rn - series
1       Jan 01    1   1      0
1       Jan 02    2   2      0
2       Jan 03    3   1      2
2       Jan 04    4   2      2
1       Jan 05    5   3      2
1       Jan 06    6   4      2
```

As long as the difference between the two schemes is the same, the series are uninterrupted. Each interruption breaks the series.

This means that the combination of (`action, diff`) defines the uninterrupted groups.

We can group by `action, diff`, find `MAX` and `MIN` within the groups and filter on them.

If you need to select `14` rows rather than `14` consecutive days, just filter on `COUNT(*)` instead of the `DATEDIFF`.

Comment: I should have been more specific!  How do you do N actions?  Specifically 14 (without 14 different subselects preferably)

Comment: Looks good, I'll test it shortly.  I definitely need sequence and not just count(*).  We're looking for patterns of behavior.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT: This would have worked for the original question about two in a row. 14 in a row is a different answer**

First you need a sequence so you are going to use ROWNUMBER

You can do a SELF-JOIN Maintenace to itself using ROWNUMBER = ROWNUMBER + 1

Any two consequitive rows with the same customer id, and both rows with "2" ActionType are will give you the list CUSTOMER as your answer.

Try this

```
WITH Maintenance AS
(
SELECT 1 as Customer, CONVERT (DateTime, '1/1/2008') DateTimeStamp, 1 ActionType
UNION
SELECT 1, '3/1/2009', 1
UNION
SELECT 1, '3/1/2006', 2
UNION
SELECT 2, '3/1/2009', 1
UNION
SELECT 2, '3/1/2006', 2
)
,RowNumberMaintenance AS
(SELECT  ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY Customer, DateTimeStamp)  AS RowNumber, *
FROM Maintenance)
SELECT m1.Customer
From RowNumberMaintenance M1
    INNER JOIN RowNumberMaintenance M2
        ON M1.Customer = M2.Customer
        AND M1.RowNumber = M2.RowNumber + 1
WHERE 1=1
        AND M1.ActionType <> 2
        AND M2.ActionType <> 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
WITH dates AS (
  SELECT CAST('2007-01-01' AS DATETIME) 'date'
  UNION ALL
   SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, t.date) 
     FROM dates t
    WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, t.date) <= GETDATE())
   SELECT m.customer, 
          m.actiontype
     FROM dates d
LEFT JOIN MAINTENANCE m ON m.last_login = d.date
    WHERE m.last_login IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select customerID, count(customerID)
from maintenance
where actiontype = 2
group by customerID
having count(customerID) >= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that by a sequence you mean two or more rows with sequential datetime values with no other rows in between for the same user with a different action type. That being the case, this should give you what you're looking to get:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
     T1.customer
FROM
     Maintenance T1
INNER JOIN Maintenance T2 ON
     T2.customer = T1.customer AND
     T2.action_type = 2 AND
     T2.last_login > T1.last_login
LEFT OUTER JOIN Maintenance T3 ON
     T3.customer = T1.customer AND
     T3.last_login > T1.last_login AND
     T3.last_login < T2.last_login AND
     T3.action_type <> 2
WHERE
     T1.actiontype = 2 AND
     T3.customer IS NULL
```

The SQL does just what I said above - finds a row (T1) with another row after it (T2) both with action_type = 2 where there is no row in between (T3) with a different action type. The T3.customer IS NULL checks for NULL because if the column is NULL (I'm assuming that it's a NOT NULL column) then it means that the LEFT OUTER JOIN must not have found a row that matches the criteria.