# Continous Counting of Present Days

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have table in sql database named as `Attendance_Master` having fields `Emp_Code,Attendance_Date,Shift,Attendance_Status(for storing Present ,Absent Status)`.

I want to count continuously 10 days attendance where `attendance_ status` is present and `shift` is III .

I am using VB.Net 2008 for coding. How could I do this?help appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! Please take a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What did you try already?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server, find an arbitrary sequence of values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820877/sql-server-find-an-arbitrary-sequence-of-values)

Comment: You could count the number of different days, if it's 10 then they attended all days.

Answer (score -1):

You need a sql statement that will collect all records where the attendance_date is **BETWEEN** the two dates you are interested in and the shift = III. Using **Count** will give you a count of how many attended.

As moffelje metioned more information is needed but if you search for sql tutorials they will give you examples of using Count and Between.